# iOS Simulator NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 after upgrading to OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, ios-simulator, ios9, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

After I upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan, my simulator can no longer connect to my local server. The same simulator has no problems connecting to my remote production server.

I'm sure my local server is running fine as Safari can connect to it properly using the same port.

Here's the error I'm getting in Xcode:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:9000/sites, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:9000/site, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=2, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

I'm running xcode 7.0.1
Simulator iOS 9.0

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was fixed after upgrading to 7.2.

Comment: Thanks. You also need to make sure that you're using the latest simulator. At the time of writing, XCode 7.3/iOS 9.3 are the latest versions. I was using 7.3 with iOS 9.1 results and I saw this error message.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug according to the Xcode 7.1 beta 3 release notes: "When running in the iOS simulator, an app cannot communicate with TCP/IP services locally hosted by the Mac. (22453539)"

Comment: thanks , saved my time in digging to find why my code doesnt work any more since the upgrade ...

Comment: This bug is still present in Xcode 7.1 (7B91b). They suggest using localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this problem persists only on simulator while real device work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) can solve this problem miraculously. Just keep Charles opened, and the problem will go away.